# How to link a menu item to a PDF

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a website, [assyrians.com](https://assyrians.com) using WordPress and I am trying to link a menu to a PDF. The problem is, when I click on "Trial Election," it downloads the PDF file immediately. What I want is to be able to click "Trial Election" and for it to lead to the PDF document as a ready-to-read display instead of an immediate download.

I apologize if that sounds confusing. I would be happy to clarify. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assume any users have viewers so always offer as a simple choice. Place download above frame not hidden at bottom, you can pretty that up but most users understand hyper underlined addresses.

[image]

```
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <p><a href="http://assyrians.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/AEIPamphlet3Jan2020-converted.pdf"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;">Click here to download your copy of the Assyrian electoral system pamphlet</span></a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <p><iframe width="98%" height="90%Vh" title="AEIPamphlet3Jan2020-converted.pdf" src="http://assyrians.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/AEIPamphlet3Jan2020-converted.pdf">A PDF frame</iframe></p>
                </div>
```

Adjust `height="90%Vh"` as desired and you can optionally add `sandbox` attribute if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.g. the Download Manager plugin, it is not the optimal solution to upload stuff like PDFs or DOCX directly into the media section.

You can use the download link as a menu item, like /?wpdmdl=1234, where "1234" is the id of the Download Manager item.

The main reason is, that all users can decide what todo with "downloads", you can not force what they have to do with it. If I decide to open PDFs in browser, so it opens, if not, I get the download box.